# Can't deploy container registry to web app for container

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I tried to create test project with docker support (windows container) and deploy it to azure container registry. After that i tried "Deploy to web app" function from menu and after successful deploy only thing i can see on my resource is "Your App Service app is up and running" and i can't access my pages of methods from my app. What can be done with this?

Comment: Could you please check docker image `expose` port number?

Comment: Could you please add your docker image information?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **WEBSITES_PORT** configuration in your WebApp. In general the WebApp Service should detect the open port automatically and match it to 443 or 80 but in some cases it helps to set **WEBSITES_PORT** in the WebApp Configuration.
You can do this for example via CLI command `az webapp config appsettings set --name <myname> WEBSITES_PORT='3000'`.
You should restart the application afterwards.